# How to includes all images in jar file using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I made a java application and bundled all classes in a jar file. When I run the project from eclipse, my application is running successfully. But when I try to run my `.jar` file, I am not getting the icons used by my application. In the code I get my icons from images directory present in project folder. How can I present these image files to the end user when using a jar?

I am loading the image like so:

```
 final public ImageIcon iReport=new ImageIcon("images/Report.png");
```

I have also tried

```
final public ImageIcon iquit=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/quit.png"));
```

and

```
final public ImageIcon iquit=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/quit.png"));
```

But this results in an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Show us some code? How are loading them that it works sometimes but not others?

Comment: You should review how you access the image resource in your code. Make sure its a relative url accessible within the jar file!

Comment: You may have a look at class.getResourceAsStream()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to get it from the classpath instead of from the local disk file system.

Assuming that `images` is actually a package and that this package is inside the same JAR as the current class, then do so:

```
final public ImageIcon iReport = 
    new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Report.png"));
```

Comment: Then the path is plain wrong. Do you understand when you need to use the leading slash `/`? Do you understand how relative paths work?

Comment: Ok thanks,I get it....but now I am getting different problem ,it all works fine using eclipse but doesnt work after making jar....actually jar file is not running.

Comment: Where exactly are you calling this line? In the class inside the JAR? Are you sure that the image is in a package called `images`?

Comment: Yes images are in package images,and jar file also content it but my jar file is not executing ....how could it be?

Answer (score 2):

The files in jar files are treated as "Resources". you need to access them as a classpath resource, regular File access methods does not work there.

Try this:

```
final public ImageIcon iReport = (new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/Report.png")));
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked long ago, but it might help others with the same problem, like me. I was already using getClass().getResource("..."), but the resource didn't get exported with .jar file.
I solved the problem by refreshing the 'Resources' folder, and its every subfolder.

Comment: I hope this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9278270/1057230) will definitely help you :-) More info can be found in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230)

Answer (score 1):

100% works

```
final public ImageIcon iReport = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Report.png"));
```

Don't forget about "/" at `path` for image.