# Java IO can't read input file?

Tags: java, image, applet

I have just started learning java and I've been working on this code for a moving object with keyboard input. I am now trying to add in a background, but it keeps erroring with:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at game.GameLoop.run(GameLoop.java:24)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The code I have in Game.java is:

```
package game;

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Game extends GameLoop{

    public void init(){
        setSize(864,480);
        Thread th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();
        offscreen = createImage(864,480);
        d = offscreen.getGraphics();
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        d.clearRect(0, 0, 864, 480);
        d.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
        d.drawRect(x, y, 20, 20);
        g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void update(Graphics g){
        paint(g);
    }
}
```

And here is my GameLoop.java:

```
package game;

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class GameLoop extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener{

    public int x, y;
    public Image offscreen;
    public Graphics d;
    public boolean up, down, left, right;
    public BufferedImage background;

    public void run(){
        x = 100;
        y = 100;
        try {
            background = ImageIO.read(new File("background.png"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(true){
            x = 100;
            y = 100;
            while(true){
                if (left == true){
                    x-=4;
                }
                if (right == true){
                    x+=4;
                }
                if (up == true){
                    y-=4;
                }
                if (down == true){
                    y+=4;
                }
                if ( x <= 0 ){
                    x = 0;
                }
                if ( y <= 0 ){
                    y = 0;
                }
                if ( x >= 843 ){
                    x = 843;
                }
                if ( y >= 460 ){
                    y = 459;
                }
                repaint();
            try{
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        }
    }

    //@Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 37){
            left = true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 38){
            up = true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 39){
            right = true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 40){
            down = true;
        }
    }

    //@Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 37){
            left = false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 38){
            up = false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 39){
            right = false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 40){
            down = false;
        }
    }

    //@Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Sorry about the editing I can't seem to get it all in the ``, and I will also fix the messy code, but do you guys have any ideas what is causing this error, there is a file in the src dir called background.png, it is very basic and made in MS paint, if that helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Different IDEs require different locations for files such as text or image resources. Try copying the image to several different locations, most likely one level above `src`, to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Is ur file in same directory ?

Comment: Just use absolute addressing so there will be no ambiguity, unless the picture is held in the application's jar file. Then you'd need to use the image as a resource, not a file.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I added it to all my directories, I'll go through and find out what it was that fixed it. I am using eclipse.

Comment: To check the default directory path: File here = new File(".");
    System.out.println(here.getCanonicalPath());

Comment: @AngusMoore - I had a similar problem a week or two ago, I'm pretty sure with Eclipse the level above `src` is the one you want. Glad I could help!

Comment: Second question, I'm running in a java applet, How do I remove those ugly bars saying applet and applet started?

Comment: It was the in the directory bin. thanks anyway

Comment: Applets won't (in most cases) allow you to read files.  You will need to emeded the resource in the Jar our deploy it within the same context.  Better to use `JPanel` and `JFrame`

Comment: `background = ImageIO.read(new File("background.png"));`

I used this inside a try catch. It works!

Comment: @AngusMoore And the image was loaded ..

Comment: When put inside the bin directory. I believe I posted the code in the original post. I have used that exact same code, and it works.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan  Good advice generally, but this is for an application resource (my best guess) in an applet (as per code).  As a result I would be looking to use an `URL` in place of the `File`.

Comment: @AngusMoore : Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9278270/1057230). Hope it sorts things out for you :-)

Answer (score 4):

There are two places a simple, sand-boxed applet can obtain images.

### Where

1. A loose file on the same server the applet was supplied from.  E.G. This might be used for a sand-boxed 'image slideshow' where the image names are supplied in applet parameters.
2. A Jar on the run-time class-path of the applet.  Best for resources which would not typically change (barring localized images, where it becomes more complicated).  E.G. This might be used for button/menu icons, or BG images.

`"background.png"` strongly indicates the 2nd scenario - 'part of the app. itself'.

### How to find

Both types of resources should identified by `URL` (**do not try to establish a `File`** as it will fail when the applet is deployed).

The way to obtain an `URL` for the 2nd case is something along the lines of:

```
URL urlToBG = this.getClass().getResource("/path/to/the/background.png");
```

..where `/path/to/the/` might simply be `/resources/` or `/images/`.  It is the path within a Jar on the classpath, where the image can be found.

### How to load

Most methods that will load a `File` are overloaded to accept an `URL`.  This notably applies to `ImageIO.read(URL)`.

While the `Applet` class has inbuilt methods to load images, I recommend sticking with `ImageIO` since it provides more comprehensive feed-back on failure.

### Further tips

#### Tip 1

```
Thread.sleep(20);
```

Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

#### Tip 2

It is the third millennium, time to start using Swing instead of AWT.  That would mean extending `JApplet` instead of `Applet`.  Then you might shift the logic of painting into a `JPanel` that is double-buffered by default, and could be used in either the applet or a frame (or a window or a dialog..).

#### Tip 3

```
setSize(864,480);
```

The size of an applet is set in HTML, and the applet should accept whatever size it is assigned and work within that.  Taking that into account, statements like:

```
d.clearRect(0, 0, 864, 480);
```

..should read more like:

```
d.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Comment: Very impressive..

But the answer to my question was inside the bin directory, which is where eclipse locates the resources, thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you still using a `File` to load it?

Answer (score 1):

@Patricia Shanahan Your comment actually helped me to solve the same problem.

I've used that code:

```
File here = new File(".");
try {
    System.out.println(here.getCanonicalPath());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and from there you can figure out the correct path to use.