# How To Export A Jar With An Image?

Tags: java, eclipse, image, deployment, embedded-resource

I want to export my jar file in eclipse with images. When i export it the program works but when i move the q.jpg the program fails, any suggestions?

```
public class image {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Collin");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("path//q.jpg");
        JLabel label = new JLabel(image);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `q.jpg` in the jar or on the file system?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes

Comment: Yes to what? If it's in the jar, how are you moving it?

Comment: @AndrewThompson eclipse

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No, it is not in the JAR, i think that is what i need to figure out

Comment: Make a source folder in eclipse, call it, ex., `resources` and put your image files in there. You'll have to reference them from the classpath and not from some file system location.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yeah, I missed that detail in my quick scan of the question.  :P

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ive done some more browsing and have gotten to `public URL imgUrl = this.getClass().getResource("res//images//q.jpg");`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis but when I put imgUrl in my ImageIcon it says that it cannot make a static reference

Comment: @Dilan Something like that will work if the `res` folder is in the same folder/package as the class of the `this`. As for the static reference error, make your variable static (if it's outside the main).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis *"You'll have to reference them from the classpath"*  Good point.  The OP might look over the [embedded resource info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form an URL based on the class-path.

Comment: ++ To what @AndrewThompson just said.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis when I make it static i cannot use `this.` anymore

Comment: @Dilan But you can use `image.class`, or whatever your class is.

Comment: Then use `URL imgUrl = image.class.getResource("res/images/q.jpg")`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It is in the same package and is set to be a source folder

Comment: @Reimeus that worke, but now i get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at twerk.frame(twerk.java:20)
 at twerk.main(twerk.java:29)
` error

Comment: @Reimeus   [picture of](http://i.imgur.com/PAfDf6w.jpg)

Comment: Try this `image.class.getResource("/images/q.jpg")`

Comment: @Reimeusit still dosnt work

Comment: It has to be in an images folder for you to refer to it from there.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it is, it is in res/images/q.jpg

Comment: @DilanHanrahan : Please try to follow these steps as mentioned in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9278270/1057230)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load an image file from a Java package is not that complicated. But if the picture is not so great, you can include it in the code. Try with the next:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String encodeImage = 
    "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAWCAYAAADAQbwGAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAilJREFU\n" + 
    "OI2llE1IVGEUhp+Z0AhkHPpzZspGN4kmltUYYmKTJC0kkgQxzEhhIsp+sFUtomUg06IiCoICoU3K\n" + 
    "UCTE3dQmgkpoiGyMFk2CMCEtpFnYyNvCcex273UudFbf5bzn4bznHK5HkigS375/pbRkDcFAVTEp\n" + 
    "yEWcHzorl1K5UgEClJr+/P/AwaMdBaCbLosq/oYB2t/auqreky+yjTKfh1/ztnN33Il3tYWZYOUr\n" + 
    "z/7eXucip9ZP9PUUbG4HKRBTQ2mZAAX9zpNyzER2N5iWcAkkLmicnQL08NGobZ2t5cTTcd5OJhkA\n" + 
    "uH+awRY/IcIMYNBFPQDp2Yx7y9tA7xckwn6JJp0hrBvs0kuOKEtA0fgVHe7o1L2rw0Us53LqOXlc\n" + 
    "aysql5IV/iXbtGueLv2mVoCef0lJWhSg29fO2QNvjtzSoaYt2lEVVHNztCDoG70rKvN3uGer7rx+\n" + 
    "slIMenBxWC1Bjxk4cn1ImzcEJEm9bXv17M2kxcqnhazVXn5il0/1F95egA/TGcrDVQA8fvWOzn2N\n" + 
    "llnXlqxzPL2NjRFqNq03L6U9ekCAvF6vpROn+DEzI0A19fXWGRqGIUAfk0nXwGXbx7q7zcBEIuH6\n" + 
    "b2IHBNQWjZo7nJiYsAXGYjHV1dUpFAopHo87AlOplBm4nPxXWF1dLcMwNDY2Jp/PZ3KSTqctTZi+\n" + 
    "XuTnCOhgJFLUJqCfc3POQEnKzM5qMZdzhC3H1NSUslnrbf4BzetqQcm3njYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=\n";

    byte[] imageData = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encodeImage);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imageData));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);
}
```

It is not common, but it works.

You can convert an image to string using something like the following.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    int option = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Files.copy(Paths.get(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toURI()), out);
        sun.misc.BASE64Encoder encoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
        String base64Str = encoder.encode(out.toByteArray());
        System.out.println(base64Str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the `sun` classes is very fragile.  Instead look to `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` which has methods like `printBase64Binary`..  But really, the OP should figure how to achieve this the conventional way first.

Comment: Humm... I did not know about `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`. Thanks!

Comment: Ehh.. (shrugs) a +1 for ingenuity..  :)