# How to load images in deployed application?

Tags: java, deployment, embedded-resource

Thanks,I'm using WINDOWBUILDER (JBWILDER) First I create a folder called displayImage in my project called Magasin, I put all images I need in my application , then to load image I go to properties -> icon->absolute path in file system I browse I go to my project this is my project path("C:\Users\CLAUDE\workspace\Magasin\displayImage\load.jpg) automatically generate code look like this

```
JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel(""); 
lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\Users\CLAUDE\workspace\Magasin\displayImage\load.jpg")); 
lblNewLabel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED)); 
lblNewLabel.setBounds(48, 11, 305, 153); panel.add(lblNewLabel);
```

Comment: I'm sure we'll spot the problem if you'd actually showed the code responsible for displaying the images.

Comment: First of all, are your images in the classpath? If so most likely you set not the local paths. Could you provide the code?

Comment: Show us the code.Without code we are blind-folded.

Comment: Show the code. I presume that image path is hard coded.

Comment: @fofo : Try to walk through the steps as specified in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9278270/1057230)

Answer (score 1):

By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource).  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. 3) 'can anyone help me?' is usually too vague a question to actually encourage people to help.  OTOH 'How to load images in an installed application?' is more clear & specific.