# How come making my own package gives me issues?

Tags: java, image, nullpointerexception, embedded-resource, imageicon

I am learning the basics of programming games in Java.  For some reason every single time I created a program with an `ImageIcon`, I would get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
at game.Picture.<init>(Picture.java:14)
at game.Main.<init>(Main.java:11)
at game.Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

After some experimenting, I found out that when I use the default package that eclipse creates, the program works fine.  However when I create my own package, the program returns an error.

Below I have two identical programs, the only difference is one uses the default package and one uses my own package called "game"

[image]

I included a view of the package explorer in case it's a problem with the location of `ship.png`

Comment: Is `ii` not null ????

Comment: I think it is in the location. Try using /raw/ship.png instead of raw/ship.png. In the game example, it will look for /game/raw/ship.png.

Comment: *"Thanks for all the help,

-Steven"*  Don't include noise in questions.

Comment: @BruceMartin  You should make that an answer.

Comment: @Steven : Try performing the steps cited in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9278270/1057230)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is in the location, you should use **"/raw/ship.png"** instead of "raw/ship.png"

try:

```
   ImageIcon il = new ImageIcon(this.getClass()
                .getResource("/raw/ship.png");
```

In the current code "raw/ship.png" will be translated by Java to **Package_Name/raw/ship.png** which in the example below is **game/raw/ship.png**. Obviously if the code is run from the **default package** (package_name=""),  **Package_Name/raw/ship.png** becomes **/raw/ship.png** and it works.

```
package game;

...

   ImageIcon il = new ImageIcon(this.getClass()
                .getResource("raw/ship.png");
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. You mean `.getResource("/raw/ship.png"));`