# Error while getting image from resources folder

Tags: java, swing, javax.imageio

(First of all, I'm sorry If there is like a million questions like this. I've tried everything I can and this is driving me nuts!)

I'm trying to had an icon to a JButton but  I keep getting an `IllegalArgumentException` caused by ImageIO.

Here's what I have:

```
    //Other UI elements ^
    JButton X = new JButton("Clear");        
    //com.oliveira.ux is the package name
    Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/com.oliveira.ux/resource/gtk-clear.png"));
    Icon clear = new ImageIcon(img);
    //More UI elements
```

The Icon is located under src/*PACKAGE NAME*/resource/. (I use eclipse).
I've tried to change the location on the code above (the one I wrote here was the last one I tried) but all I get is an IllegalArgumentException when I run de .jar. Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance

Here's the full error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.oliveira.ux.Main.<init>(Main.java:146)
    at com.oliveira.ux.Main.main(Main.java:75)
    ... 5 more
```

This points to the ImageIO part in the code I wrote above.

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace, along with any "caused by" sections, and indicate the statement in your code that is throwing the exception.

Comment: `getClass().getResource()` looks for a file relative to the current class's location, so if your class is already inside of the com.oliveira.ux package, then you only need to pass it `"resource/gtk-clear.png"`. As an aside, packages are folders, so com should be a folder, oliveira should be a subfolder, and so on; therefore, you would do something like com/oliveira/blah/blah.

Comment: Is this `com.oliveira.ux` suppose to be a web reference or a package path reference.  If it's a path, it should not be separated by `.` but `/`

Comment: @sbat that did it, thank you! I thought it was separated by dots because of eclipse... Didn't even remember of checking the file system. Anyway thanks

Comment: @MadProgrammer it's the package name

Comment: @Luso : Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960381/runnable-jars-missing-images-files-resources/9278270#9278270). Hopefully this might be able to help a bit :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path appears to be wrong...

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/com.oliveira.ux/resource/gtk-clear.png"));
```

`getResource` isn't expecting the pack name, but the "path" to the resource from the context of the class path (so the path is appended to the class path elements)

Something like...

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/com/oliveira/ux/resource/gtk-clear.png"));
```

Should give a better result