# How do I load images in Jframe java(eclipse)?

Tags: java, image, swing, gif, paintcomponent

I have an paneel.java file which looks like the following code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Paneel extends JFrame
{
    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
        // frame
        JFrame frame = new Paneel();
        frame.setSize ( 1000, 1000 );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setTitle( "Remembory" );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
    
    class Gifpaneel extends JPanel{
        private ImageIcon gif, animatedGif;
        
        public Gifpaneel() {
            gif = new ImageIcon( "test.gif" );
            animatedGif = new ImageIcon( "animaties/test.gif" );
        }       
        
        public void paintComponent( Graphics g ){
            super.paintComponent( g );
            
            gif.paintIcon( this, g, 100, 100 );
            animatedGif.paintIcon ( this, g, 250, 100 );
        }
        
    }
}
```

I would like to show the test.gif file.
How do I get this done? because when I run it in eclipse I only get the jframe with no image in it.

Comment: You haven't added created a Gifpaneel object and added it to your JFrame.

Comment: how do i get this done?

Comment: Please have a look at how to [add images to Eclipse Project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9278270/1057230), and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230) for more information. Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageInFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String path = "Image1.jpg";
        File file = new File(path);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(label);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocation(200,200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to set a file path to the image..something like this

```
final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\you\\Desktop\\test.gif");
```

Comment: Although a good suggestion, that's not the big issue here. If the absolute path is not set, it will use a path relative to where it is being executed from.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main ( String [] args )
{
    // frame
    JFrame frame = new Paneel();
    frame.setSize ( 1000, 1000 );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setTitle( "Remembory" );

    // Add following
    GifPaneel gifpan = new GifPaneel();
    gifpan.repaint();
    frame.add(gifpan);


    frame.setVisible( true );
}
```

Comment: Please do not call `paintComponent(...)` explicitly, that is not the job of the programmer, just call `gifpan.repaint()` which will call `paintComponent(...)` implicitly :-)

Comment: Actually, in this specific case, you are not even suppose to call `repaint()` as well, since `frame.setVisible(true)` will do that implicitly :-) For the rest You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Answer (score -1):

create package named as images on your project file and import image in that perticular package. Now, take a lable and select the icon property and select image from class path.

Comment: FYI, Stackoverflow understands English only!

Comment: This answer would hugely benefit from some example code. As is... this looks like a valid attempt at answering the question, but it isn't a very good attempt, so I wouldn't expect anyone to upvote it. Even so, it is an attempt, so I'm marking it as "Looks OK" in response to a flag someone raised suggesting that it should be deleted.