# My code does not show images from frame

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, embedded-resource

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;




public class Concentration extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JButton buttons[][]=new JButton[4][4];
    int i,j,n;

    public Concentration() {

        super ("Concentration");    
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        setSize(10000,10000);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,4));
        panel.setSize(4000, 4000);

        for( i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){
            for (j=0; j<buttons[i].length;j++){ 
                n=i*buttons.length+buttons[i].length;
                buttons[i][j]=new JButton(new ImageIcon("1.jpg"));

                panel.add(buttons[i][j]);

            }
        }
        add(panel);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Concentration();
    }

}
```

I put the images in images folder in package folder but it doesnot show. What am i doing wrong?

I will make a memory game but still cant do anything. And should i use label instead of icon to show picture?  Or jtogglebutton or jbutton?

Comment: By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Comment: `setSize(10000,10000);`  What screen is this intended for, the JumboTron?

Comment: made http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960381/runnable-jars-missing-images-files-resources/9278270#9278270 here but now an exclamation mark near my project. I restarted refreshed. There seems no errors but it wont execute and show my window? I made a imagefolder in source, in it an images file and uttons[i][j]=new JButton(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/1.jpg"))); but it does not work. –

Comment: The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved. the error is that.but my project has imagefolder and in it images folder. How can this be

Comment: if I don't misunderstand your file system like that : {imagefolder/images/*.jpg} , you should use new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagefolder/images/1.jpg"));

Comment: Now i have bigger problem. I deleted images folder, i deleted the part of image from code and added "something" and it still executes the deleted images? i restarted a lot of times but still same. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image is internal (you want a location relative to your project, or perhaps packaged into your jar) :

```
new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/1.jpg"));
```

The path is relative, so path/ will be a folder in the same folder as your project (or packaged into your jar).

If you want an external image, simply hand ImageIcon constructor the path (ex. "C:/.../file.png"). This isn't recommended though, as it's better to use it as a resource.

For more info on the ImageIcon constructor, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html). for more info on loading class resources, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E18745_01/apidocs/oracle/adf/view/faces/resource/ResourceLoader.html) (Javadoc links)

Comment: ImageIO would generally be a better choice as it throws an Exception when issues arise when loading the image and it loads the image in one call, not using a background thread...IMHO

Comment: Be carefull! bin is a temporary file, each time Project/Clean is invoked bin is cleared!

Comment: @johnbrown: well heck, why are you asking the same type of question again? You should then already know about system resources.

Comment: i dont know about it, i can not do now