# How to add a image file into the Java Swing Frame?

Tags: java, swing

I tried to add an jpg image file into my Java Swing page, 
but when running, system always back error "Source not found" and stucking there.
the source code are following

```
this.setLayout( new BorderLayout( ) );
URL url = getClass().getResource("logo");
ImageIcon imageicon = new ImageIcon( url );
JLabel label = new JLabel( imageicon );
this.add( label, BorderLayout.NORTH );
```

The file name is: "unStudent.java", and image file is "logo". I have put the both files in the same folder, why system can not find image file? what should I change?

Thanks in advance.
Tony

Comment: Where is "logo" stored and also, is that the correct name? What IDE are you using?

Comment: I have change image file's path to whole path as below, this.setLayout( new BorderLayout( ) );
  URL url = getClass().getResource("C:\\Documents and Settings\\evergreen\\workspace\\login\\src\\login\\logo");
  ImageIcon imageicon = new ImageIcon( url );
  JLabel label = new JLabel( imageicon );
  this.add( label, BorderLayout.NORTH );

Comment: but error is same, I use Eclipse

Comment: Two things, I might consider using `getClass().getResource("/login/logo")` instead and you might need to move the `logo` file out of the `src` directory to the "resources" directory within in the project directory as Eclipse doesn't like resources been stored in the `src` directory...generally...

Comment: Usually, where should this image file put, under /src and with *.java files?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't tend to like anything else other the *.java files to be stored in the source directory.  Resources should be stored in a `resources` folder within the same directory as the `src` folder. You might need to tell Eclipse to include this directory as part of it's run/build process, not 100% sure as I don't use Eclipse, I just know the issue exists

Comment: @user3837183: Please have a look at how to [add images to Java project in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9278270/1057230) and how to [add images to Java Project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), for some detailed insight. Hopefully this be of some help in your endeavour :-)

Comment: Thank you MadProgrammer, I switch to higher version Eclipse and put logo file under /bin forder, then I can see the image. I believe old Eclipse has bug for handling image

Answer (score 0):

Try this method to create your `ImageIcon`. Make it public or private, it's up to your design.

```
private ImageIcon createIcon(String path)
{
    URL url = getClass().getResource(path);

    if(url == null)
    {
        System.err.println("Could not load the icon: " + path);
    }

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);

    return icon;
}
```

now make sure that `path` is the correct path to the file and **with the file extension**.
I'm quite sure your mistake, or one of your mistakes, is the file extension missing. So if your `logo` file is a `png` image type and it is stored in `c:\images` your `path` must be `c:\images\logo.png`

I would recommend you to place your images inside your project folder.

PS; pay attention to `\` escaping. I assume you know it.

Comment: This isn't adding anything to what the OP is already doing. You shouldn't be using getResource with absolute paths, that's the point of using getResource.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I switch to higher version Eclipse and put logo file under /bin folder, then I can see the image. I believe old Eclipse has bug for handling image

Answer (score -1):

Try this soluion:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("logo.jpg");
```

if it does not works try to put the absolute path of your image as follows:

```
URL url = new URL("C://folder/logo.jpg");
```