# Can't access application resource using getResource()

Tags: java, image, resources

First off let me start by stating what my project path looks like really quickly.

```
project/src/application/<.java files>
project/src/img/<.png files>
project/bin/application/<.class files>
project/bin/img/<.png files>
```

Eclipse was smart enough to duplicate my img folder in the bin folder once I created under the src folder.

The code in question is the following (called in the CardImage class):

```
BufferedImage myPic = ImageIO.read(CardImage.class.getClass().getResource("/img/1.png"));
```

From what I can tell, this is the correct way of grabbing the images off the bin/img folder. Yet I continue to get the following error.

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
```

I've read similar questions and answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369171/jcomponents-not-showing-up-with-picture-background/11372350#11372350) but can't seem to figure out why it's not working. Also I'm not entirely sure if the getClass() call was necessary after doing

```
CardImage.class
```

Comment: I am really sorry for the late reply. Was a bit offline for a long long time, with my own thingies. Do try to follow these steps, as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9278270/1057230). If it still not working, please do let me know. Many apologies for being late.

Comment: It doesn't work. I even wondered if having my code in a package might be causing the problem.

Comment: It doesn't work. I even wondered if having my code in a package might be causing the problem but that's not it.

Currently my path looks as [such](http://imgur.com/WPVGwRZ).
The code for grabbing these is
`java.net.URL picURL = CardImage.class.getClass().getResource("/img/" + ((15 - c.getRankInt()) * 4 - suit) + ".png");
   ii = new ImageIcon(picURL);`

Comment: Now it doesn't run when I export to a jar file AND it also doesn't work when I try to run off eclipse. [This](http://imgur.com/DZHttkS) is what it looks like if I look at the root of the jar file. The img folder has the correct images inside it.

Comment: Have you created a source folder, as mentioned, and then added `img` folder to it and inside this `img` folder, the images for the project !!!!!

Comment: OMGGGGGGGGGGGGGG. The... there was another piece of code that was getting the images but it used the old `new File` syntax to do it (I didn't know any better back then)... This meant that even when I got everything else right, it still wouldn't run in an executable jar file. It also explains why I could run the program on eclipse with certain file configurations... Oh man, this is what I get for not reading the errors properly... Almost a month and a half lost to misread error that I never bothered reading after the first time. Sigh...

Thank you SO MUCH.