# Runnable exported JAR not running as it should when out of Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I export my project from my IDE, Eclipse into a runnable JAR the program does not work as it should.

What should appear when launched and what appears when launched from Eclipse:

[image]

What appears when the program is launched after exporting:

[image]

As you can see it does not seem to work as it should and as I've only been doing this for a while now please keep the language simple so I can understand.

How it works:
[image]

**EDIT NOTE**

I put a few showMessageDialog in a few places to see what would popup and if anything would popup with numbers to know which ones and one popped up from middle of the game class but not the one I put at the top.

Comment: Do you load any resources ? What happens when they are not found ? Do you set anything special in the run configuration ? Do you catch exceptions without reacting to them ?

Comment: http://puu.sh/ocOcK/ce85b77380.PNG

Comment: Wow, this is what I call an extensive reply ...

Comment: Are the resources included in the jar?

Comment: nothing is displays once exported so maybe not

Comment: If you believe the resources are included in the JAR, then try writing some code to test for their existence. I agree with @Marged too - if you can add as much detail as possible in your responses to him or her, they may think of something that you can try.

Answer (score 1):

This issue probably relates to the fact that you use images in your game but they are not included in your jar.

If you are not accessing your images using the method described here, you need to: [Runnable JARs missing Images/Files (Resources)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960381/runnable-jars-missing-images-files-resources)

Comment: http://puu.sh/ocVAn/755495f9c9.PNG
I did what it told me up till "Now in order to access..." but I have the same thing going on except I have a class that does this(refer to image)