# Uploading entire Processing project on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I want upload an entire processing project, with images and fonts, to Eclipse. I know how to do it with my main or one class, but how can I move all my classes into it?

If there are identical questions then I didn't see them, and I apologise.

If someone can help me me out with this then I´ll be so grateful.

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense. What exactly do you mean by **uploading to eclipse**? You don't upload anything to eclipse. What exactly do you do with a main class? Why exactly doesn't that work with multiple classes? What are you trying to do? Can you provide more details or screenshots of what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing the project using the Import option?

Check this link for how to add images

[Runnable JARs missing Images/Files (Resources)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960381/runnable-jars-missing-images-files-resources/9278270#9278270)

Comment: I doesn't give me the option through the Import button, buddy.