# Set Executable Jar Icon Missing

Tags: java, swing

I using Eclipse to export a runnable JAR file from my project file.
But the icon image never shows after export. It works when I run through
eclipse but not after creating the JAR.

Here is my code that I have in my main method:

```
frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images/icon.gif"));
```

Image is the correct directory. Also, tried method using BufferedImage but did not work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5):

images in a JAR file are treated as resources. You need to use

```
getClass().getResource("images/icon.gif")
```

and then use ImageIcon or other techniques to get the image. See:

[How to includes all images in jar file using eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373021/how-to-includes-all-images-in-jar-file-using-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

An example of how I did:

```
    Image image =Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("wood.jpg"));
```

The above method worked for me when creating a runnable jar.

Hope it helps.