# Where do I store images so that an executable jar file can access them?

Tags: java, eclipse, image, executable-jar

I am using Eclipse to make an executable jar file of a game I created, but when I create the jar and run it, the images in the game no longer show up. Where do I store the images so the jar file can access them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373021/how-to-includes-all-images-in-jar-file-using-eclipse

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put them in the jar, and then use `Class.getResource`, `Class.getResourceAsStream`, `ClassLoader.getResource` or `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` to access them. Which is most appropriate depends on what else you're doing, but you might want something like:

```
Image image = new Image(Program.class.getResource("/images/foo.jpg"));
```

... where `Program.class` is *any* class within the same jar file. Or if you're storing your images in the same folder as your classes (by the time you're deployed) you could just use:

```
Image image = new Image(GameCharacter.class.getResource("knight.jpg"));
```

That's a *relative* resource name. (Relative to the class in question.)

Comment: If I type it like that, it says "Cannot Instantiate the Type Image". I have a class called Resources and an image called MountainBackground, so I wrote                                 Image image = new Image(Resources.class.getResource("MountainBackground.png"));

Comment: @user2081893: That was just a random example - hence the "something like". We don't know what sort of app you're writing, or what image class you're using. You should adapt it accordingly - or provide more information in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.net.URL; 

URL imageURL = getClass().getResource("/Icon.jpg");
Image img = tk.getImage(imageURL);
this.frame.setIconImage(img);
```

Answer (score 1):

My file structure is:

```
./ - the root of your program
|__ *.jar
|__ path-next-to-jar/img.jpg
```

Code:

```
String imgFile = "/path-next-to-jar/img.jpg";
InputStream stream = ThisClassName.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream(imgFile);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(stream);
```

Replace `ThisClassName` with your own and you're all set!

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you embed them within the jar file?

**UPDATE:** How I did in one of my assignments is as follows:
Embedded the images in the jar file, and:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/banana.jpg");
if (url == null)
{
    // Invalid image path above
}
else
{
    // path is OK
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);
}
```