# why are my textures not working?

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, textures

My textures have only been working in Eclipse but when I try to export it as a runnable jar ill start it up and there is no textures. I made a resources folder and connected it to the project by making it a class folder but it only works in eclipse. this is how I usually access the textures.

```
Image something;
public Image getsomethingImg(){

    ImageIcon s=new ImageIcon("res/something.png");
    something=s.getImage();
    return something;
}
```

Then i draw it.

```
g2d.drawImage(getsomethingImg(), 0, 0, null);
```

Comment: You should check locations of your textures after build/deploy. It might be worth reviewing those paths, as they may be different then in Eclipse project.
"res/..." could work in Eclipse as a base path will be project root, but running project outside might need full path like "C:\...."

Comment: 1) `g2d.drawImage(getsomethingImg(), 0, 0, null);` should (in all likelihood) be `g2d.drawImage(getsomethingImg(), 0, 0, this);`. 2) Don't try to load images in the paint methods! 3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Please have a look at this answer, [adding resources to project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230). Hope it will help you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to includes all images in jar file using eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373021/how-to-includes-all-images-in-jar-file-using-eclipse)

Try this next.

```
ImageIcon s = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("res/something.png"));
```

Comment: It is safer to use `ImageIO` to read images since if the path is wrong, it will throw informative exceptions.

Comment: this is a nooby question but how would I write that? like in a class I keep getting errors.

Comment: @liamspeakman : Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230), that might can give you this idea :-) Moreover, do not keep the `ImageObserver` part as `null`, in your `g2d.drawImage(getsomethingImage(), 0, 0, compReferenceOnWhichYouDrawing)`

Comment: compreference? like what class,what main draw method am i using,or something else? sorry if this a stupid question I am only about 5 months into java coding.