# Images disappearing after creating Jar file

Tags: java, image, jar, loading

So I have a playable game where there are images that are stored in my flashdrive. However, after exporting the jar file to my desktop, and unplugging my flashdrive, the images disappear in my game. If that is so, how are the people who play my game going to see my images if I put my jar file online for them to download? In my code I upload the images to my code like this:

```
static Image LimageFishy = new ImageIcon("F://Picture//Lfish.png").getImage();
static Image RimageFishy = new ImageIcon("F://Picture//Rfish.png").getImage();
```

Comment: Why don't you ship them with your jar file?

Comment: Include your image inside Jar fine and load them as resource.

Comment: How do I ship them? What is ship?

Comment: Pshemo, I don't know how to do that. Can you give me steps please. thanks.

Comment: @Pshemo just tagging you.

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie  just tagging you.

Comment: Well, to `ship` is to distribute. And when I say that you should ship your image with the jar, I mean that you should put the images in the jar and then load them from the jar. If the images in the jar, people can download everything bundled in a single jar.

Comment: There are lot of questions about that, for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373021/how-to-includes-all-images-in-jar-file-using-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

This is a method you could use:

```
private ImageIcon createIcon(String path) {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
    return icon;
}
```

Make sure that you put the image in the correct path though. For instance, if you have a package "images" and it contains a file "Rfish.png", then `path` needs to be `/images/Rfish.png`.

This is a great resource: [Loading Images Using getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource__1)

Notes:

- the `/` at the start of the path; it is easily missed).
- the names inside a jar are case-sensitve: `Rfish.png` isn't the same as `rfish.png`